# Use accented characters with REST API parse

Tags: c#, parse-platform

I'm using parse to send push messages. I created a simple tool to allow admins to send messages to the users.

This function works fine, the problem occurs when I pass a string like "Você recebeu uma mensagem" to the pushMessage variable. This occurs because I'm using the character "^". If I use the same string in the parse push panel, the message is sent.

How can I parse the string to prevent this problem in C#?

**Parse.cs**

```
  private bool PushNotification(string pushMessage, string title, string canais)
    {
        bool isPushMessageSend = false;

    string postString = "";
    string urlpath = "https://api.parse.com/1/push";
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlpath);
    /*postString = "{ \"channels\":"+ canais +", " +
                     "\"data\" : {\"alert\":\"" + pushMessage + "\"}" +
                     "}";*/
   /* postString = "{ \"channels\":"+ canais +", " +
    "\"data\": {\"message\": \"" + pushMessage + "\",\"title\": \"" + title + "\",\"is_background\": false}}";*/
    postString = "{ \"channels\":" + canais + ", " +
   "\"data\": {\"data\": {\"message\": \""+pushMessage+"\",\"title\": \""+title+"\"},\"is_background\": \"false\"}}";

    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.ContentLength = postString.Length;
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-Parse-Application-Id", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-Parse-REST-API-KEY", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
    requestWriter.Write(postString);
    requestWriter.Close();
    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    try
    {
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

            if(responseText.Contains("true"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Mensagem enviada com sucesso");
            }

        }
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Problema ao enviar mensagem\nErro:"+e.ToString());
    }

    reset();
    return isPushMessageSend;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried encoding the string before sending it in the request?

Comment: @Alexander no, how can i do this?

Comment: Can you clarify the issue more? Is it that parse does not accept the diacritic ^?

Comment: @Ghasan the problem occurs when using caracters like "~" "´" "º" "^" , this is used in portuguese language to send msgs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stick to UTF-8 when working with JSON.

```
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
```

and put the correct ContentLength in bytes which dependes of Encoding format:

```
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postString).Length;
StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()); //UTF-8 by default
```

Full example [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8vE8fk)

[image]

As you can see in the screenShot the "ê" character is enconded in UTF8 with octal values  \303\252 and you can see in [this table](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=oct) that this correspond to: LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH CIRCUMFLEX

If the server is not able to parse this then it has a big problem as parsing UTF-8 is like the bread and butter in internet.

Comment: You've marked this as an answer. Did it work for you? If not, what didn't work about it?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to encode pushMessage before sending it and ask front end developer to decode message property in JSON